# How can I show Interstitial ad from Non Activity Class?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have a non activity class named custom adapter which shows images on main activity which loads images from the internet and sets wallpapers on click
I want to show interstitial ad from Non Activity class,(CustomAdapter) when image view is clicked 
Tried many stuff but doesn't work out , plz help me out

**Custom Adapter.java**

```
    class CustomViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    RibbonLayout ribbonLayout;
    ImageView imageView;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ribbonLayout = (RibbonLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ribbonLayout);
        imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    List<Item> itemList;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Item> itemList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item = itemList.get(position);
        if (item.type == 0) { //new
            holder.ribbonLayout.setShowBottom(false);
            holder.ribbonLayout.setShowBottom(false);


            holder.ribbonLayout.setHeaderRibbonColor(Color.parseColor("#2B323A"));
            holder.ribbonLayout.setHeaderTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

            holder.ribbonLayout.setHeaderText((item.headerText));
            Picasso.with(context).load(item.imageURL)
                    .into(holder.imageView);
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) view).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

                        Toast.makeText(context, " \\ (•◡•) /Yay! Wallpaper Set \\ (•◡•) / ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the context from Activity class to Non-Activity Class while setting the adapter. And the simply use the context whenever you want to show the Ad.

Comment: _Tried many stuff but doesn't work out._ Show us what have you tried.

Comment: @Kunu these two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012359/how-to-put-an-interstital-ad-inside-an-adapter-class                                                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703207/showing-admob-interstitial-in-non-activity-class

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 can you please write it out as a answer, Will help other people too

Comment: If something worked for others and not for you then you must be doing something wrong. And unless you show your code and what error are you getting then it is difficult to debug your problem.

Comment: @Kunu  I get this error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.isLoaded()' on a null object reference

Comment: Error clearly saying you are trying to show ad on a null object. First initialize your Interstitial ad object.

Comment: @AnishJain I have given an answer. Please check and tell if it works fine for you or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call an Interstitial Ad like this from a Non-Activity Class

```
  Custom Adapter.java

        class CustomViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RibbonLayout ribbonLayout;
        ImageView imageView;

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ribbonLayout = (RibbonLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ribbonLayout);
            imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }

        }

        public class CustomAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder> {

        Context context;

        List<Item> itemList;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Item> itemList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.itemList = itemList;
        }

        @Override
        public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Item item = itemList.get(position);
            if (item.type == 0) { //new
                holder.ribbonLayout.setShowBottom(false);
                holder.ribbonLayout.setShowBottom(false);


                holder.ribbonLayout.setHeaderRibbonColor(Color.parseColor("#2B323A"));
                holder.ribbonLayout.setHeaderTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                holder.ribbonLayout.setHeaderText((item.headerText));
                Picasso.with(context).load(item.imageURL)
                        .into(holder.imageView);
                holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) view).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

                            Toast.makeText(context, " \\ (•◡•) /Yay! Wallpaper Set \\ (•◡•) / ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Activity.ShowAd();//Hope you want to call the ads from here.
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return itemList.size();
        }
    }
```

And this is your Activity Class

```
    Activity.java

    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when when the interstitial ad is closed.
    }
});
            // Make sure to set the adapter after the above code.
        }

      public static void ShowAd()
        {
           if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note- 1) Change all the ad Ids as these are the test Ids.
      2) Call the set adapter code after requesting for the Interstitial Ads
      3) Also, see that the time taken by the user is sufficient so that the ads 
        is loaded.**

Comment: Thanx it worked, just needed to add Adlistener further

Comment: @AnishJain Added the listener code also. You can let me know if you need any help regarding that also.

Comment: Nope I did that part, but thanx for adding , it may help some other people looking for answers

Comment: @AnishJain Glad, it helped you.